# How to upload image to Java sever in Swift

Tags: java, image, swift, upload

I try to upload a image to Java sever in Swift.There is a Java code that can upload the image

```
public class UploadUtil {
    private static final String TAG = "uploadFile";
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 10*1000;  
    private static final String CHARSET = "utf-8"; 

    public String uploadFile(File file,String RequestURL)
    {
        String result = null;
        String  BOUNDARY =  UUID.randomUUID().toString(); 
        String PREFIX = "--" , LINE_END = "\r\n";
        String CONTENT_TYPE = "multipart/form-data";  

        try {
            URL url = new URL(RequestURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(TIME_OUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT);
            conn.setDoInput(true);  
            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            conn.setUseCaches(false);  
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");  
            conn.setRequestProperty("Charset", CHARSET);  
            conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "keep-alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", CONTENT_TYPE + ";boundary=" + BOUNDARY);

            if(file!=null)
            {
                /**
                 * 当文件不为空，把文件包装并且上传
                 */
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream());
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                sb.append(PREFIX);
                sb.append(BOUNDARY);
                sb.append(LINE_END);

                sb.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"img\"; filename=\""+file.getName()+"\""+LINE_END);
                sb.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset="+CHARSET+LINE_END);
                sb.append(LINE_END);
                dos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int len = 0;
                while((len=is.read(bytes))!=-1)
                {
                    dos.write(bytes, 0, len);
                }
                is.close();
                dos.write(LINE_END.getBytes());
                byte[] end_data = (PREFIX+BOUNDARY+PREFIX+LINE_END).getBytes();
                dos.write(end_data);
                dos.flush();
                /**
                 * 获取响应码  200=成功
                 * 当响应成功，获取响应的流
                 */
                int res = conn.getResponseCode();
                Log.e(TAG, "response code:"+res);
                //                if(res==200)
                //                {
                Log.e(TAG, "request success");
                InputStream input =  conn.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer sb1= new StringBuffer();
                int ss ;
                while((ss=input.read())!=-1)
                {
                    sb1.append((char)ss);
                }
                result = sb1.toString();
                Log.e(TAG, "result : "+ result);
                //                }
                //                else{
                //                    Log.e(TAG, "request error");
                //                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I need write the code with swift but I can't solve those problem:
How to get the filename?I don't find any way to get picture path in swift.
This is my code(Swift) now

```
func uploadImageOne(){
    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)

    if imageData != nil{
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"Enter Your URL")!)
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        var boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
        var contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)
      //  println("Content Type \(contentType)")
        request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        var body = NSMutableData.alloc()

        // Title
         body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Hello World".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)

        // Image
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_img\"; filename=\"img.jpg\"\\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(imageData)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



        request.HTTPBody = body


        var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

        var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println("returnString \(returnString)")

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get image path you have to write image into a file at specified directory first and thats the missing part in your code. The easiest way is to write in user documents directory by doing so:

```
let fileDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

func uploadImageOne(){
    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)

    if imageData != nil{
        //image path
        var imageFilePath = fileDirectory[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("temp.png")
        var imageFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilePath)
        imageData.writeToURL(imageFileURL!, atomically: false)
        ...
    }
}
```

And after your image is successfully uploaded you can delete your temp file by using NSFileManager

```
var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var error: NSError?
fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path, error: &error)
```